# Stateful custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component, `StatusIndicator`, that uses a Redux Toolkit query, `q`, to fetch a status value and display it.

I want to write a custom hook, `usePolling`, that can be configured using arguments to invoke `q` at intervals, updating `StatusIndicator`.

I have two problems:

1. Even though I specify a dependency on `isAuthenticated`, the contents of the custom hook run repeatedly.
2. How do I separate the state for each instance of the custom hook? I am using useState in an attempt to maintain the `timeoutId` for each instance. Is this correct?

```
export const StatusIndicator = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const { data, q } = useGetStatusQuery();

  usePolling({ callback: q }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (<div>{{data.status}}</div>);
};

export const usePolling = ({ callback }, dependencies = []) => {
  const [instanceTimeoutId, setInstanceTimeoutId] = useState(null);

  // I only want this run when `isAuthenticated` changes
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function continuation() {
      clearTimeout(instanceTimeoutId);
      await callback();
      const { timeoutId, promise } = delay(interval);
      setInstanceTimeoutId(timeoutId);
      await promise;
      continuation();
    })();

    return () => clearTimeout(instanceTimeoutId);
  }, [...dependencies]);
};
```

Comment: I see you're using `useState` for `instanceTimeoutId`. I think you can just use a variable within `useEffect` instead. `useEffect(() => {let instanceTimeoutId = null; (/* async func */)(); return () => clearTimeout(instanceTimeoutId); })`. There's a good chance the hook is re-rendering because of the state change.

Comment: Yeah, or perhaps try storing your `timeoutId` in a ref instead of state. As `timeoutId` isn't being used to control your UI, a ref is more appropriate. Also, the clean-up function of your useEffect only knows about the `instanceTimeoutId` when the useEffect is called, and not the new value it gets set to when it's changed using `setInstanceTimeoutId` (due to the closure you get for `instanceTimeoutId`), you won't get this issue if you use a ref.

Comment: As for the `useEffect` not triggering upon change in the provided dependencies, I suspect it has to do with the fact that you are creating a copy of said dependencies. At which point they receive new references. Try using the `dependecies` prop directly.

Comment: First problem can be resolved by defining a separate `useEffect` hook something like: `useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return;
    }`
Also, If I had to free will to modify the arguments for `usePolling()` hook I would have used a third optional param `const usePolling = (callback, isAuthenticated, interval = 5000)` and used interval as dependency to my main `useEffect`

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned in my comment, you're using `useState` for the timeout handle, so every time the `continuation` function is called, it will call `setInstanceTimeoutId`, which will trigger a re-render of `usePolling` hook because of the state change.

In fact, just a simple variable should be enough here. You could probably use `useRef` for the handle, but I think the simple `let timeoutHandle` should have no issues, since we're only using the value in two places - within `continuation` and in the hook cleanup. Both will just access whatever the current value is at the time.

```js
export const usePolling = ({ callback }, dependencies = []) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutHandle = null;
    (async function continuation() {
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
      await callback();
      const { timeoutId, promise } = delay(interval);
      timeoutHandle = timeoutId;
      await promise;
      continuation();
    })();
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
  }, [...dependencies]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also have used `useRef`for storing my `timeoutId` as pointed our **@NickParsons** comment.

```js
export const usePolling = ({ callback }, isAuthenticated, dependencies=[]) => {
  const instanceTimeoutId = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(instanceTimeoutId.current);
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only start polling when isAuthenticated is true
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      (async function continuation() {
        clearTimeout(instanceTimeoutId.current);
        await callback();
        const { timeoutId, promise } = delay(interval);
        instanceTimeoutId.current = timeoutId;
        await promise;
        continuation();
      })();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, callback, ...dependencies]);
};
```

To solve the first issue inside the second `useEffect` I've checked the condition that if `isAuthenticated` is true; immediately invoke async function. This function clears any existing timeout, calls the callback function and after that set a new timeout using the delay function. Now, The timeout id is stored in `instanceTimeoutId.current` ref. After the delay is passed, the continuation function is called again.